# google chrome printing issue (different size)

Tags: css, html

[image]
this is the picture that my page looks like

[image]
this is the picture when i want to print my page

The height is different, when the css class is the same. I really don't know about this problem. Is there anyone experience this problem. FYI, I am using google chrome. When I use firefox, this issue doesn't appear, but the other thing is a mess and I want to do this on google chrome. Please help me.

Comment: Simple solution: Use Firefox, and save yourself the trouble :P

BTW could it be possible to put the code here or link to it? I might be able to check out what's going on here

Comment: the boss want to use chrome... what can i do...LOL...